# Laravel sql connection timeout

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am unable to connect to sql database via Laravel.

Problem is not: when i am using xampp or when i am working without Laravel like with normal php.
Problem is: when i try to connect to my ONLINE sql server with Laravel. (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002])

I cant publish this post still sayin some error so i am writing this text.
Something about quality standards.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql   
DB_HOST=c236um.forpsi.com   
DB_PORT=3306     
DB_DATABASE=******   
DB_USERNAME=*****   
DB_PASSWORD=*****
```

Comment: If you can't provide your code, how do you expect us to help you? You need to provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your MySQL Server is not listening incoming connections. You have to verify:

1. Edit your my.ini file and change the bind parameter from 127.0.0.1
   to 0.0.0.0 for to allow external connections to MySQL.
2. Verify that port 3306 is open in your firewall.

Kind regards.